# How do I stack multiple images from different folders using Matplotlib in Google Colab?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to stack two different folders of images on top of each other in two rows in Google Colab using Matplotlib. However, I only get an odd output of an empty plot and one image below that.

```
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
%matplotlib inline

front_images = []
for img_path in glob.glob('drive/My Drive/chaospicsf/*.png'):
    front_images.append(mpimg.imread(img_path))
back_images = []
for img_path in glob.glob('drive/My Drive/chaospicsb/*.png'):
    back_images.append(mpimg.imread(img_path))


fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
fig.suptitle('Vertically stacked subplots')


columns = 2
for i, image in enumerate(front_images):
    axs[0].plot(len(images) / columns + 1, columns, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(image)

for i, image in enumerate(back_images):
    axs[1].plot(len(images) / columns + 1, columns, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(image)
```

The output *(current plot)*:

[image: current plot]

This was a *previous plot* when I used the same axes for both folders and didn't specify different subplots and axes:

[image: previous plot]

Comment: As it does plot the back_image, it could be that your front_images are not created properly. check if the front_images is empty

Comment: @FloridaMan I've checked, it definitely has the images in and they aren't corrupted or anything, so it should work, rather frustratingly